# how to select service account json in google app credentials cloud speech to text api,DeadlineExceeded: 504 Deadline Exceeded

Tags: google-cloud-platform

i can't even run the sample diarization on my own wav file because of google credentials error. I ve got service account made and downloaded json file in the same directory.

```
from google.cloud import speech_v1p1beta1
import io

def sample_long_running_recognize(local_file_path):

client = speech_v1p1beta1.SpeechClient.from_service_account_file('speech-diarization-2bc027502c2e.json')
#client = speech_v1p1beta1.SpeechClient.from_service_account_json('speech-diarization-2bc027502c2e.json')

language_code = "en-US"
config = {
    "enable_speaker_diarization": enable_speaker_diarization,
    "diarization_speaker_count": diarization_speaker_count,
    "language_code": language_code,
}
with io.open(local_file_path, "rb") as f:
    content = f.read()
audio = {"content": content}

operation = client.long_running_recognize(config, audio)

print(u"Waiting for operation to complete...")
response = operation.result()

for result in response.results:
    # First alternative has words tagged with speakers
    alternative = result.alternatives[0]
    print(u"Transcript: {}".format(alternative.transcript))
    # Print the speaker_tag of each word
    for word in alternative.words:
        print(u"Word: {}".format(word.word))
        print(u"Speaker tag: {}".format(word.speaker_tag))

sample_long_running_recognize(local_file_path='diarizationExample.wav')
```

It gives me the error:

```
DeadlineExceeded: 504 Deadline Exceeded
```

Comment: Could you try the [online API](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/reference/rest/v1p1beta1/speech/longrunningrecognize) and see if it fails with same error?

Comment: @Ksign, thx but what is this? i give it my json api key?

Comment: No, you don't have to give your api key. In the request body, enter your audio file source and your config and click **EXECUTE**, you will be prompted to select your account for the API to use your credentials. By the way and just in case, the code you posted is not indented and I don't see your `enable_speaker_diarization` and `diarization_speaker_count` variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

p.s. i forgot to add that i tried to run it 2 times - one on office corporate machien and my own laptop. You need to make 2 separate keys, each json service acc key is downloaded to your machine. it's private key! 1 for 1 machine.
So i gnerated new json service key for my home machine.

this is  fully working solution:

```
!pip install google-cloud-speech

import os
os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"]="your_json_file.json"

from google.cloud import speech_v1p1beta1
import io


def sample_long_running_recognize(local_file_path):
    """
    Print confidence level for individual words in a transcription of a short audio
    file
    Separating different speakers in an audio file recording

    Args:
      local_file_path Path to local audio file, e.g. /path/audio.wav
    """

    client = speech_v1p1beta1.SpeechClient()

    # local_file_path = 'resources/commercial_mono.wav'

    # If enabled, each word in the first alternative of each result will be
    # tagged with a speaker tag to identify the speaker.
    enable_speaker_diarization = True

    # Optional. Specifies the estimated number of speakers in the conversation.
    diarization_speaker_count = 2

    # The language of the supplied audio
    language_code = "en-US"
    config = {
        "enable_speaker_diarization": enable_speaker_diarization,
        "diarization_speaker_count": diarization_speaker_count,
        "language_code": language_code,
    }
    with io.open(local_file_path, "rb") as f:
        content = f.read()
    audio = {"content": content}

    operation = client.long_running_recognize(config, audio)

    print(u"Waiting for operation to complete...")
    response = operation.result()

    for result in response.results:
        # First alternative has words tagged with speakers
        alternative = result.alternatives[0]
        print(u"Transcript: {}".format(alternative.transcript))
        # Print the speaker_tag of each word
        for word in alternative.words:
            print(u"Word: {}".format(word.word))
            print(u"Speaker tag: {}".format(word.speaker_tag))

sample_long_running_recognize(local_file_path='diarizationExample.wav')
```

this gives smth like this:

```
 Waiting for operation to complete... Transcript: all I was receiving
 in the United Kingdom and I was told it I didn't need it on here
 because I don't think they should get it because it is my order out
 there than it is over here saying should get it then not paying for
 fuel in this country Word: all Speaker tag: 0 Word: I Speaker tag: 0
 Word: was Speaker tag: 0 Word: receiving Speaker tag: 0 Word: in
 Speaker tag: 0 Word: the Speaker tag: 0 Word: United
```